# Chrome opens download links in a new tab as a file instead of downloading the file on mac os

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari

I'm trying to download jquery 3.4.1 compressed, but when I click on the download link on [jQuery's official website](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery), chrome just opens the content inside the jQuery file in a new window instead of downloading it.

[An image of the jQuery website and the link I clicked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dftQm.png) Sry I still can't embed images yet so it's a link

[Here's an image of the tab chrome opens when I click on the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LxKG.jpg)

BTW this also happens if I use Safari so I'm not sure if it's a problem with chrome or macs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happens, just use the **File → Save** ("Save Page As…" in chrome, or however your particular browser spells it) function of your browser after clicking on the link. At least for files that aren't HTML, you'll get the same result as if the file automatically downloaded.